# MySQL primary key renaming

Tags: mysql

I have below tables

```
1. TABLE1 (Primary Key ID)
2. TABLE2 (ID Foreign key reference from TABLE1)
3. TABLE3 (ID Foreign key reference from TABLE1)
4. TABLE4 (ID Foreign key reference from TABLE1)
5. TABLE5 (ID Foreign key reference from TABLE1)
```

Above all 5 tables has huge data.

Now I am trying to Rename `ID` as `OLD_ID` in `TABLE1`

I want to rename ID column by setting `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`
But unable to rename and getting below error

> Error Code: 1846 ALGORITHM=COPY is not supported. Reason: Columns
>   participating in a foreign key are renamed. Try ALGORITHM=INPLACE.

I know If I drop Foreign key from all the child table then renaming easily we can do. But remvoing and adding foreign key in the child table taking lot of time due to the huge data.

Please suggest what are the best way to rename primary key field??

I am doing this activity in MySql.

Comment: do you know the name of the foreign key constraint ?

Comment: Yes. I know  the constraint name

Answer (score 6):

Actually its a bug in MySql - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82946

according to which - With foreign_key_checks=0, InnoDB permitted an index required by a
foreign key constraint to be dropped, placing the table into an
inconsistent and causing the foreign key check that occurs at table load
to fail. InnoDB now prevents dropping an index required by a foreign key
constraint, even with foreign_key_checks=0. The foreign key constraint
must be removed before dropping the foreign key index.

also mentioned in mysql reference document - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks

So u have to first drop the foreign key

The solution is to first drop the foreign key, then change the column, finally adding the constraint back in.

```
ALTER TABLE `TABLE1`
DROP FOREIGN KEY `mytable_oldname_fk`,
CHANGE COLUMN oldname newname INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
ADD CONSTRAINT `mytable_newname_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`newname`) REFERENCES `anothertable` (`id`)
```